# レイティングを利用した推薦システムのアルゴリズム手法について

Tags: アルゴリズム

現在、レビューサイトにおける商品推薦システムのアルゴリズム改善に携わっております。

検索者が希望条件（例えば、機能、価格、使いやすさなど）とその重視度を入力すると、商品の利用者であるレビュアーが入力した各要素のレイテイングをもとに検索者の希望条件に合致すると思われる商品をランキング形式で提示し、商品詳細とレビューが見れるようなサイトです。

そこで質問なのですが、上記のような商品推薦システムにおいて一般的に用いられるアルゴリズムにはどのようなものがあるのでしょうか。

例えば、検索エンジンの場合だとクエリとテキストの類似度を算出し類似度順に表示するランク学習、レコメンドエンジンの場合だと協調フィルタリングやアイテムベースでのレコメントなどよく知られたアルゴリズムがあると思うのですが、検索者が具体的な希望条件とその重視度を選択するようなシステムの場合、どのようなアルゴリズムを適用するのが一般的なのか知見がないので教えていただけますと幸いです。

イメージ的には職業マッチングサービスやマッチングアプリのように、希望条件を入力して希望に合った求人情報や相手を提示するサービスによく用いられているアルゴリズムを知りたいです。

よろしくお願いします。